# Filter table for data, but use other data also (.Net Reporting Services 2008)

Tags: reporting-services, filter, dataset

I am building a report which gets data from a dataset containing 10 rows. Every row has a key figure (1-10). For one table in the report, I only want to display the data from row 1, so I filter the table for key figure 1. But I also need the data, let´s say, from row 5 to display some data calculated together with the data from row 1.
What is the best way to do this? 
I could try to get the data from the dataset directly, but don´t know how.
Also, I could expand the table filter for row 5, but wouldn´t this cause the table to display more data than intended?
I use Visual Studio 2008 and SQL Server 2008 as TargetServerVersion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Filter the dataset to return all the rows that you want data from (in this case, row 1 and row 5).
2. Conditionally suppress the detail row in your tablix (via the Visibility: Hidden property in the Properties Window) so that it is hidden for the rows that you don't want to display (in this case, row 5).